# Is there a way to write to an invalid memory access?

Tags: c, memory-management, linker, memcpy, nxp-microcontroller

I'm defining memory region to store incoming data, but this regions are not initialized as I'm defining them through pointers (the pointers represent start/end), so when I'm trying to copy data (write) to it, the system throws a segmentation fault. NOTE: I already checked my address and it's pointing to an unused memory region.

I already tried filling the memory beforehand, defining the memory region into the linker script, but no workaround saves me from getting a hard fault.

Edit: I'm working within an embedded system, I KNOW the pointer is pointing to invalid memory (unused), so the thing I want to achieve is either validate such memory region before using it or a workaround the fault.

Comment: When you say "I already checked my address and it's pointing to an unused memory region." what does that really mean? Is this memory you've gotten from `malloc` or some other mechanism? Modern operating systems don't just let you poke around wherever you'd like.

Comment: Also, just because you have a 32- or 64-bit address space, that doesn't mean every pointer value actually points to valid memory, or that usable memory appears just because you create a pointer to some unused address.  Typically, a process will be running on an operating system like Windows or some Linux distribution.  The operating system controls what memory the process actually has access to and the addresses the process can use.  You can use `malloc()` or other standard C calls to get memory, or you can use system-specific calls like `mmap()` in POSIX systems like Linux.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Re "*that doesn't mean every pointer value actually points to valid memory*", A system could auto-allocate memory pages. But it's far more valuable to seg/protection fault.

Comment: @ikegami I did think about systems like that in the context of non-hosted systems. But I'm on my way to bed because I have to wake up in 6 hours or so for a long commute to work and don't have time for a full, actual answer, hence the comment restricted to hosted systems.

Comment: @Andrew Henle, My comment *is* about systems with virtual memory (which is what I think you mean by "hosted system"). My point is that it doesn't matter if it actually points to valid memory or not. That's not the issue.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to access memory that it shouldn't be accessed, the fault is actually a good thing, so... How do you make it accessible?

Comment: By definition, an invalid memory address is one you can't write to or read from, so no, you can't write to it, because then it would not be invalid.  Note that "unused" is completely different from "invalid".  In order to make a memory region valid, you need to arrange for memory to be at that address, which is a matter of hardware.  If you're using an MMU, it is a matter of programming the MMU.  If not using an MMU its a matter of physical hardware (wires and chips).

Answer (score 2):

It's not enough to ensure the memory is unused.<sup>[1]</sup> The memory management system needs to be made aware that the memory is now being used. This is typically done by requesting memory using `malloc` or `calloc` (but there are other system-specific means of obtaining memory).

These functions provides a pointer to memory that is unused after marking it as allocated. Marking is as allocated ensures that future allocations won't use that memory (unless it has been freed in the interim). And it makes sure the OS doesn't throw a segfault when you use that memory.

---

1. It's not evident to me that this is even possible. And if it is, it would surely be more complicated than simply using `malloc`/`calloc`.

Comment: In a sense I AM trying to allocate memory, BUT to an specific address (or region/section), can it be done?

Comment: There's no reason to do that. What are you [actually](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) trying to accomplish?

Comment: My embedded firmware system needs to allocate memory regions for image storage, I'm trying to do so in the hardware abstraction layer, instead of the linker script, for portability.

Comment: I'm guessing you're saying you want to write to a specific address so that the hardware or some other process can find it. In a system with virtual memory, memory addresses are specific to a process. They don't refer to a specific location. An address can point to a page that's not even in RAM, and it can be at different places in RAM at different times. This is all completely transparent to the process. That's the virtual in virtual memory. So the question is: Does your system use virtual memory?

Comment: Whatever the answer is, C doesn't provide the answer. I'll be something specific to your system. You might even need to write the code to be part of the OS and use functions internal to the OS.

Comment: That's probably the case, I just wanted to know if anyone had dealt with something similar before. Just to be clear, it is not virtual memory, it's an unused memory region, and the OS has nothing to do with it. It's about the microcontroller and its processor, but yeah, I get your point, I guess it's just protected against that kind of stuff, which I think is good, but I was wondering if it could be done as it'd "ease" my life, handling memory by hand is great if you know your way around (in embedded systems at least).

Comment: Re "*the OS has nothing to do with it*", uh. The OS is the one killing your program. It has *everything* to do with the OS. /// Re "*it is not virtual memory, it's an unused memory region*", You obviously don't know what you're saying. /// Your comments have been completely unhelpful. Please address the questions I raised.  What are you actually trying to accomplish? Does your system use virtual memory?

Comment: This is a baremetal project, it doesn't have an OS, the one killing my system is the MPU - Memory Protection Unit, or something similar, that's one of the things I'm not totally sure about. So, there's an external flash memory which I divided into different regions, you can think of them as storage units, I can read from them at runtime, through pointers because I know the addresses and sizes, but I can't write to them in the same way because it's not allowed, that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: The MPU acts as the OS here. You will need to satisfy the MPU. Everywhere I said OS, pretend I said MPU. (And the system surely doesn't use virtual memory.)